# Invalid syntax CASE statement

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, case

I've been struggling all day with a really simple case statement in SQL...

I have this piece of code:

```
UPDATE `alugueis`
    SET    `status` = CASE
             WHEN `pago_em` is null THEN 'Atrasado'
             WHEN `pago_em` is '' THEN 'Atrasado'
             ELSE `status`
           END
WHERE  `vencimento` <= CURDATE()
```

and the error I get is: [1064][42000]: (conn:235) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual .......

I don`t think I am mixing up the two forms of CASE, or am I?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1):

I think you intend:

```
UPDATE alugueis
    SET status = (CASE WHEN pago_em is null THEN 'Atrasado'
                       WHEN pago_em = '' THEN 'Atrasado'
                       ELSE status
                  END)
    WHERE vencimento <= CURDATE();
```

The problem is the `is ''`.

This would more normally be written without the `CASE`:

```
UPDATE alugueis
    SET status = 'Atrasado'
    WHERE vencimento <= CURDATE() AND
          (pago_em IS NULL OR pago_em = '')
```

Comment: Tried your second implementation and it almost works. It won`t work only because pago_em is a date and it returns me "Incorrect datetime value: '' ". If I want to check if a date is not empty, checking for "IS NULL" only is enough? Thank you so much so far!

Comment: If the type is a date, then comparison to `NULL` is sufficient.

Comment: Still have a problem :/
There are some dates with the following value "0000-00-00" and they are not considered NULL, so it gives me the wrong result. How can I select them? Trying to do a lot of stuff here....

Comment: @AndréPadilha . . . You would just add the condition `or pago_em = '0000-00-00'`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry for the late response..... but it works 100% now!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `IS ''`

```
UPDATE `alugueis`
    SET    `status` = CASE
             WHEN `pago_em` is null THEN 'Atrasado'
             WHEN `pago_em` = '' THEN 'Atrasado'
             ELSE `status`
           END
WHERE  `vencimento` <= CURDATE()
```